Problem to extract correct data from PDF with tesseract
I'm trying to extract specific data from multiple PDFs. I begin by isolating the example image (Picture 1) using horizontal and vertical lines to create cells. After creating the cells, I crop them before starting pytesseract-OCR to extract the text from each cell, as shown in Picture 2.
Everything works fine until the text extraction step. The extraction only works on some cells. For example, in Picture 2, I want to extract the text "PROJEKTNAMN" and "TRANSPORTGARAGET," but only the latter is successfully extracted.
I believe this issue might be due to different font sizes. I've tried adjusting the parameters like oem and psm, but without any improvement.
Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions to help resolve this issue?
Picture 1
Picture 2
The things I have tried are:

Changing the zoom of the cropped cells.
Changing the oem and psm and language to swedish with no better results.


Can you post some code samples, how are you doing this? Are you trying to extract from the entire image or are you using rectangles with tesseract? (rectangles means more work on your end but gives more accurate results).

Sounds like the page segmentation mode (PSM) flag is not set correctly. Try the value of 4 or 11, more info on the documentation here

could you share the exact code that you are using

In Tesseract, your tessdata matters same like your preprocessing and other logics you apply on image. I will give a file which works for your image.
tessdata
Rename it as eng.traineddata amd replace that with the default one in tessdata folder
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

tesseract_path=r'/path/to/your/tesseract'
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = tesseract_path

image_path = 'HDQ9DjOy.png'
img = Image.open(image_path)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)

This gives me output, on top of which you can apply some processing to get required output,
PROJEKTNAMN

TRANSPORT GARAGET


In the question it was mentioned that cropping and selecting the required part was already done. From picture 1 getting the picture 2 was already taken care

OCR efficiency depends on selecting ROI, which varies for every use case. As per the question ROI of picture 1 is picture 2, which is already achieved by David and he needs OCR for Picture 2. We can focus on picture 2 alone. Also, the code in the question is sufficient for this use case. What we should focus is the tessdata. Most OCR application efficiency depends on training data, which is same in this case too.
